# javascript object init issue

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to init a method in my case. I have something like

```
var test = new testObj()

 function testObj(){
        this.init();
    }

 testObj.prototype.init = function(){        
    //do something
 }
```

However, I am getting `testObj has no method of init` error from the console.

I am not sure what happen. Can someone help me out on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Common people why the downvote rush.... it is a perfectly valid question with a real problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because the order of your script

```
function testObj() {
    console.log(this)
    this.init();
}

testObj.prototype.init = function () {
    //do something
}

var test = new testObj();
```

The function declaration will get [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#Hoisting) to the top of the declaring scope, so you are able to create a new `testObj` instance but the enhancement of the prototype has not happened when the constructor is called so you won't get `init` method.

After hoisting the code could look like below, when `new testObj()` is executed, it calls the constructor function but the `init` method is not yet added to the prototype of `testObj`

```
function testObj() {
    console.log(this)
    this.init();
}

var test = new testObj();

testObj.prototype.init = function () {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: oh boy..my brain is dead. I can't even find out this. thanks for the help